# parameters in this jsfiddle url

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, urlencode, jsfiddle

I am wondering how is this jsfiddle url different than the rest of the jsfiddle links,

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Mostly jsfiddles  are like [jsfiddle.net/7Yutyu](http://jsfiddle.net/7Yutyu)  but in this case I see parameters being passed like jquery version how is this done. I would also like to know if we show or hide a particular city like(tokyo , New york, Berlin or London) can that be added to the url query string.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the integration with GitHub:
http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_read.html

```
URL: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/{framework}/{version}/{github_tree}/
```

Here's an example that they provide on the documentation page:

```
Example
Demo on the github: http://github.com/zalun/jsFiddleGithubDemo/tree/master/Demo/
URL to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/mootools/1.2/zalun/jsFiddleGithubDemo/tree/master/Demo/
It will load the fiddle with MooTools framework in version 1.2.5
```

Also, here's the actual GitHub page that's being used from example in the question:
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

As for the part of tquestion about passing variables into jsfiddle, it looks like the only thing that can be passed this way is the framework that is used to display the GitHub code.

Comment: Actually I need to know how to pass the parameters from high chart graph to url and  append them, when say some line is hidden(say city Berlin)